# KVM bridge; guest unable to reach gateway

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I have a server. It's configured with a public IP, and I have /29 subnet assigned via a network bridge.

KVM is installed and works as intended. I can create and boot a VM, but when it comes to defining network access things start to go wrong.

If I manually enter the IP for the Guest (which comes from the /29). I enter the host IP as the gateway, and then I get the message that the gateway is unreachable.

Here's the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 144.76.15.98
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 144.76.15.97
  pointopoint 144.76.15.97
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.120 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.121 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.122 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.123 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.124 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.125 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.126 dev br0
  up route add -host 136.243.185.127 dev br0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what’s behind your `eth0` interface, but it looks wrong to bridge your external network with your virtual network, given that they use different IP addresses.

I think things would work much better if you set up your host computer as a router between eth0 and br0.

Things might also be easier if you used your 136.243.185.120/29 as a subnet rather than route it IP by IP.

You would have something like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 144.76.15.98
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 144.76.15.97

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 136.243.185.121
  netmask 255.255.255.248
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
```

You’d also have to enable packet forwarding with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

If you can’t afford to “loose” 3 addresses in your 136.243.185.120/29 network, you can configure `br0` with address `144.76.15.98`, netmask `255.255.255.255` and manually route your 8 addresses to that interface, as you did.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The box in question is hosted with Hetzner and I followed this guide: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_-_the_easy_way/en

But I'll try your suggestion tonight. I'd rather lose some IP's to get this working, than feel an overwhelming urge to throw the box out the proverbial window.

Comment: I just had a look at that tutorial, and it looks more like my second suggestion than like your config: in the host, the physical interface is **not** part of the bridge, and the bridge is configured with the same IP as the external interface, with netmask 255.255.255.255.

Comment: The problem is that when I follow the above suggestions, I end up with VMs that return "gateway unreachable". This occurs when I try to install Ubuntu on the guest and I end up having to configure the network manually (because obviously, no DHCP)

Comment: What configuration did you try for the host? (Subnet or routes to the individual hosts?) And how did you configure the VM’s network?

Comment: I've set it up with individual routes. I have a VM up and running, but can't get the host/guest connection working on a non-lan ip.
I've configured the VM with two nics; one running 10.0.0.x and one running the above /29. But it ain't taking. But I'll get to the bottom of this. :D

Comment: @Thomas Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issues, also on Hetzner.

Comment: Hey. Yea. I did. For me it was because the firewall on the host prevented communication with the guests.